# R - plotting specific columns as x with two rows as the lines

Tags: r, plot

Here is a small sample of my data:

```
    gene_name ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t0 ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t1 ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t2
22     ABP140          -0.262682          -0.303352          -0.223626
246      ARI1          -0.163952          -0.374765          -0.321876
454      BPH1          -0.517519          -0.524553          -0.747609
513      BUR6           0.645573           0.217433           0.390403
588     CDC20          -0.264072          -0.665268          -0.594191
    ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t3 ctrl_lsm1_stat_t0 ctrl_lsm1_stat_t1 ctrl_lsm1_stat_t2
22           -0.421704                no                no                no
246          -0.692391                no                no                no
454          -0.793595                no                no               yes
513           0.200799               yes                no                no
588          -0.523884                no               yes               yes
    ctrl_lsm1_stat_t3 systematic_name
22                yes         YOR239W
246               yes         YGL157W
454               yes         YCR032W
513                no         YER159C
588               yes         YGL116W
```

I would like to plot columns [,2:5] on the x axis (as in time point 0, 1, 2, and 3) with the y axis fitting the ratio columns.

If there's a way to color the points to be one color for "yes" or "no" at the specific time points, I would also like to be able to do that. (for instance, points in the ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t0 column would be colored based on values in the ctrl_lsm1_stat_t0 column).

I also only want to plot two rows at a time, both as lines (for instance row 22 with row 513). Hope this makes sense! I'm new to R and not sure what to do. I'm willing to download whatever package necessary.

Comment: do you want all those to appear in a single plot?

Comment: no, one plot per 2 rows. I have a reference row that I wish to compare all other rows to, individually

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example of your data with (say) `dput(head(mydata, 20))`? Just edit the output into your question

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the dput function. Are you looking for my raw data? EDIT: I tried this function with my data and it spat out a bunch of stuff. My dataframe is 54 rows by 10 columns so it might be too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.csv:

```
    gene_name,ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t0,ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t1,ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t2,ctrl_lsm1_ratio_t3,ctrl_lsm1_stat_t0,ctrl_lsm1_stat_t1,ctrl_lsm1_stat_t2,ctrl_lsm1_stat_t3,systematic_name
    ABP140,-0.262682,-0.303352,-0.22362,-0.421704,no,no,no,yes,YOR239W6
    ARI1,-0.163952,-0.374765,-0.32187,-0.692391,no,no,no,yes,YGL157W6
    BPH1,-0.517519,-0.524553,-0.74760,-0.793595,no,no,yes,yes,YCR032W9
    BUR6,0.645573,0.217433,0.39040,0.200799,yes,no,no,no,YER159C3
    CDC20,-0.264072,-0.665268,-0.59419,-0.523884,no,yes,yes,yes,YGL116W1
```

Code:

```
    d<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
    matplot(t(d[,2:5]), type="l", pch=20, lty=1, xlab="time", ylab="ctrl_lsm1_ratio")
    d2<-reshape(d[,6:9],varying=list(names(d[,6:9])),direction="long",v.name="ctrl_lsm1_stat", ids=d$gene_name)
    points(d2$time, unlist(d[,2:5]), col=ifelse(d2$ctrl_lsm1_stat=="yes",1,2),cex=2.0)
    legend("topright",legend=c("yes","no"), col=c(1,2), pch=21)
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to reformat your code a bit so it fits in a window without horizontal scrolling. More people will look at it then.